# how to parallel or multithreading 2 function in C++?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm a beginner at parallel programming. I have 2 function in my code that I want run this 2 function in parallel (multiThread). can you help me?

func 1:

```
    void Navigation::test_end(Graph::Node *node, dtPolyRef endRef, const float *endPos, int endIdPos)
{

    int k=0;

    //std::ofstream fout("v4.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
    auto it2 = myMap2.equal_range(endRef);
    for (auto it = it2.first; it != it2.second; ++it) {
        int m_npolys = 0;   
                int n=0;

             dtPolyRef m_polys[MAX_POLYS];
        int j = it->second.size();

       for(int i=0;i<j-1;i++){
           if(it->second[i]>0){
          m_polys[m_npolys++] =it->second[i];
        //  fout <<it->second[i]<<" ";
               }

       currentGraph.AddIntraEdge(node->idNode,endIdPos, node->edges[k].idPos,  it->second[j-1], m_polys ,m_npolys);  //n=m_npolys
                 k++;

    }

    }
```

==========

func 2:

```
void Navigation::test_start(Graph::Node *node, dtPolyRef startRef, const float *startPos, int startIdPos)
{


    int k=0;
    //std::ofstream fout("v4.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
    auto it2 = myMap2.equal_range(startRef);
    for (auto it = it2.first; it != it2.second; ++it) {
        int m_npolys = 0;   
                int n=0;

             dtPolyRef m_polys[MAX_POLYS];
        int j = it->second.size();

       for(int i=0;i<j-1;i++){
           if(it->second[i]>0){
          m_polys[m_npolys++] =it->second[i];
        //  fout <<it->second[i]<<" ";
               }

       currentGraph.AddIntraEdge(node->idNode,startIdPos, node->edges[k].idPos,  it->second[j-1], m_polys ,m_npolys);  //n=m_npolys
                 k++;

    }

    }
```

now i want to run this 2 function in parallel mode in the main function :

```
 test_start(sNode,startRef,startPos,startIdPos);

  test_end(eNode,endRef,endPos, endIdPos);
```

Comment: What are you having problems with specifically? Have you looked into threads?

Comment: I want to run this code ( test_start and  test_end function) to parallel mode in order to speed up run time.